# How to prevent from getting an error of an array of 0 sample (shape=(n,0)) while prediction just one row of data from a huge dataset?

Tags: python-3.x, scikit-learn

I'm currently building a prototype system that consists of a prediction work. My code is working properly and the results are perfects if I make a prediction based on several rows like the table below.
[Several rows from the dataset](https://i.stack.imgur.com/leyxN.png)

However, when it comes to predicting just one row from my dataset, like the table below,
[One row data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PExU6.png)

I am getting this error: ValueError: Found array with 0 sample(s) (shape=(0, 8)) while a minimum of 1 is required. Which means that I can't make a prediction based on only one row which is the main content of my work.

Below is my code:

Here is my code:

```
def upload_file(request):
 template='upload_file.html'
 if request.method == 'GET':
 return render(request, template)
 CSV_file=request.FILES['csv_file']

 if not CSV_file.name.endswith('.csv'):
 messages.error(request, 'This is not a CSV file')
 return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('add_pull_requests'))

 train=pd.read_csv(CSV_file) 

 features_col = ['Comments', 'LC_added', 'LC_deleted', 'Commits', 'Changed_files', 'Evaluation_time','First_status','Reputation'] 
 class_label=['Label']
 X = train[features_col] # This also test
 y=train[class_label]

 random_state = 0
 # test_size=request.GET.get('test_size')
 for train_index, test_index in loo.split(X):
    X_train, X_test = X.iloc[train_index], X.iloc[test_index]
     y_train, y_test = y.iloc[train_index], y.iloc[test_index]
 # X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, random_state=random_state, test_size=test_size)
 clf = tree.DecisionTreeClassifier()
 clf = clf.fit(X_train, y_train)
 y_pred = clf.predict(X_test)
 print('Up to here is ok')
 try:
 Accuracy="{0:.2f}%".format(accuracy_score(y_test, y_pred) * 100)
 Precision="{0:.2f}%".format(metrics.precision_score(y_test, y_pred) * 100)
 Recall="{0:.2f}%".format(metrics.recall_score(y_test, y_pred) * 100)
 F1_meseaure="{0:.2f}%".format(2*metrics.precision_score(y_test,y_pred)*metrics.recall_score(y_test,y_pred)/(metrics.precision_score(y_test,y_pred)+metrics.recall_score(y_test,y_pred))*100)
 except ZeroDivisionError:
 print("Error: dividing by zero")
 F1_meseaure='nan%'


 print("Accuracy:",Accuracy )
 print("Precision:", Precision)
 print("Recall:", Recall)
 print("F1-measure: ", F1_meseaure)

 importances_feautres = pd.DataFrame({'features': features_col, 'importance': np.round(clf.feature_importances_, 3)})
 importances_feautres = importances_feautres.sort_values('importance', ascending=False).set_index('features')

 print(importances_feautres.shape)
 importances_feautres = [ls[0] for ls in importances_feautres.values.tolist()]

 classification_report={'accuracy':Accuracy, 'pricision':Precision, 'recall':Recall, 'f1_score':F1_meseaure}

 importance_features={'importances_feautre':importances_feautres}


 data={
 'new_data':new_data,
  'classification_report':classification_report,
 'importance_feature':importance_features,
 'features':features_col,
  }

 return render(request,template, data)
```

The error comes from lines of code:

```
for train_index, test_index in loo.split(X):
    X_train, X_test = X.iloc[train_index], X.iloc[test_index]
    y_train, y_test = y.iloc[train_index], y.iloc[test_index]
```

If I replace these lines with the line below I'm getting the same error:

```
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, random_state=random_state, test_size=test_size)
```

Please assist

Comment: which line gives you the error?

Comment: This is not very clear. Are you trying to learn (fit) only on a single row?

Comment: @AI_Learning, I edited my post. Please check on the new version.

Comment: Please post the complete error.

Comment: @Vivek Kumar, yes. Because the main task is to be able to predict for a given row, if it will be reopened or not (Label=1 or 0). Is it possible?

Comment: Please first understand what it means to training and predicting. You train for a task (Label=1 or 0) using a dataset (multiple rows which contain both labels). Then you check if the performance of that model is good enough or not. That is done by train test splitting or cross-validation. Fitting the model on train data and predicting on test data. Once you are satisfied by the model, you deploy it. Then it will not learn anything new (no `fit()`), only predicts on incoming rows. And those rows can be single.

Comment: How do you hope to learn and predict on a single row? You need to find a way to persist your model (save the trained model) and then at each request you just use that model to call `predict()`.

Comment: @Vivek Kumar, thank you so much I got what you said. I used this model using the whole dataset and another persistence model pickle to make the prediction in the new single row.

Comment: So is the error solved now? If yes, post an answer about what you did.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Vivek Kumar, thank you so much. I got what you said. I used this model using the whole dataset and another persistence model pickle to make the prediction in the new single row.

```
import pickle 
model=pickle.dump(clf) # clf is coming from the above model
clf2 = pickle.loads(model)
clf2.predict(X[i:i+1]) # where i is the index of the row that we want to predict
```

I think it's ok like this unless I did not understand your proposal.